# Specifying a whitelist in Thecus N7510

Tags: nas

I use the NAS [Thecus N7510](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00921DXDE), which runs on ThecusOS. Is there any way to define a whitelist of IPs that are allowed to connect to it?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.